# Creating a Private Channel via Graph API Is Creating a Standard (not Private) Channel

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I am creating a new Team using Graph (DotNet SDK) but when I try create a Private channel, it's creating it as a Standard (shared) Channel. Code is similar to the following:

```
newTeam.Channels.Add(new Channel
{
    DisplayName = "Test Private Channel",
    IsFavoriteByDefault = true,
    Description = "Test",
    MembershipType = ChannelMembershipType.Private
});
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there perhaps a bug in the SDK?

Update: I should mention this is being specified at the time of creating the Team itself, using [this endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Answer (score 2):

So this is possible to achieve, with a workaround. When creating the Channel as part of the initial Teams creation, as described in the original question, it will ONLY create Channels as "Standard" Channels, **even if they are specified as Private**. If you definitely need the Channel(s) to be private, you need to create them separately, AFTER creating the Team, using the [`Create Channel` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

As an important follow up, even though you might have *just* created the Team, and have Team.Create permissions, you will ALSO need Channel.Create or similar to immediately create the new channel straight after.

To an MS team members following this thread, I'd like to report the following issues, in summary:

1. It's not possible to create Private channels using standard OOB Templating in Teams - this should be added
2. It's not possible to create Private channels using the Create Team endpoint - setting the MembershipType to Private is simply ignored - this would appear to me to be a bug
3. I would suggest that if my application has the rights to Team.Create, where I can create channels (just not Private ones), that should be a sufficient permission already without needing Channel.Create